# Uploading large files with HttpClient

Tags: java

I want to upload large video files (>=1Gb) with `HttpClient` to a servlet but I couldn't find any real examples. 
Could you give me some useful code examples?

---

I'd like to see both the HttpClient and FileUpload demo codes (as a one project). And it is quite interesting can I use FileUpload lib to download large files?

---

It is interesting to have upload bound like this applet -> servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of HttpClient and file upload:

http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload

I'm not sure that you mean by "real".  It's real enough, even if it doesn't precisely match your situation.

1GB?  You're likely to have file size limitation issues.   Try it locally and see.  If it fails, at least you'll have some real code and more exact conditions to post here.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply

I have found just this example

Comment: Listing 9-6. HttpMultiPartFileUpload.java

Comment: It is quite interesting but I don't see any mention of chunk or buffer? So the HttpClient doesn't have the HttpUrlConnection max_chunk_size limitation?

Comment: And I couldn't find any FileUpload example :( So I'd like to see both client and servlet example codes...

Answer (score 0):

I am able to upload large files >200mb , Please look into below jsp to spring controller code .

```
Jsp code :
<script src="../lib/app/configurator.data.ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../lib/ui/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<html>

<script language="Javascript">
var varb = '';
var test = 0;
var count = 1;
$(function () {
var maxChunkSize = 30000000; //SET CHUNK SIZE HERE
var your_global_var_for_form_submit = '';

var params = {
        year: threeDSelectedYear,
        series: threeDSelectedSeries
};
/*File upload bind with form, 'fileupload' is my form id. As sumit triggers
    for file ulaod will submit my form*/
/* replaceFileInput: true, */
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
maxChunkSize: maxChunkSize,
url: efccustom.getEfcContext()+'upload/uploadZip?year='+threeDSelectedYear+'&series='+threeDSelectedSeries,             //URL WHERE FILE TO BE UPLOADED
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Called for each failed chunk upload
        $(".fileupload-loading").html("");
         $('.ANALYZE_DIALOG').dialog("close");       
    },

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    /*This event will be called on success of upload*/
    count = parseInt($('#counter').val()) + 1;
    $('#counter').val(count);

    $('#ttk').val(count);
    data.ttk = 7;
    console.log(" count ",count , data);
    },

    submit: function (e, data) {
    /*This event will be called on submit here i am
                     adding variable to form*/
    //console.log($('#zip_uploaded_file').val());      

    //console.log(data.originalFiles[0].name);            
    test = data.originalFiles[0];
    $('#fname').val(data.originalFiles[0].name);
    $('#trequests').val(Math.ceil(data.originalFiles[0].size/maxChunkSize));
    $('#counter').val('1');
    },

    progress: function (e, data) {
    /*PROGRESS BAR CODE WILL BE HERE */
        $(".fileupload-loading").html('<img src="../public/themeroller/images/throbber.gif" alt="Uploading Please Wait..." title="Uploading Please Wait...." />');       
    },

    add: function (e, data) {
    $('.browsedFileName').html(data.originalFiles[0].name);
    your_global_var_for_form_submit = data;
    },

    done: function (e, data) {

        ajaxcall.Data._get('upload/extractZipNCreateJson',params,function(data2) {
            alert("file upload success ");
             $(".fileupload-loading").html("");
             $('.ANALYZE_DIALOG').dialog("close");
        });


    }

});
/*This is my button click event on which i am submitting my form*/
  $('#button').click(function(){
    your_global_var_for_form_submit.submit();
  });
});
</script>

<html>

<body>


<form id="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
<div class="span7">
<!--<input type="file" name="files" id="file" /> -->

<input type="file" id="zip_uploaded_file"  name="zip_uploaded_file"  />
<input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="trequests" id="trequests" value="1" />

<input type="hidden" name="ttk" id="ttk" value="1" />
<input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="submit" />
 <span class='browsedFileName'></span>
</div>
</div>
<!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
<div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
</form>
</body>


Controller COde :
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadZip", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String>
     uploadZip(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
        try {       
        String year = request.getParameter("year");
        String series = request.getParameter("series");
        log.info(" year " + year + " series " + series);
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if (isMultipart) {

            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            UserContext userContext = (UserContext) session
                    .getAttribute(ApplicationConstant.USER_CONTEXT);
            String userName = userContext.getUser();
            String workSpaceInUse = userContext.getCurrentWorkSpace();           
            FileItem item = null;
            boolean fileNotExistFlag;
            String fileExtension;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                item = (FileItem) iterator.next();

                String content = item.getContentType();
                log.info(" content "+content);
                log.info(" File Type Getting Uploaded :"+content);
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
            /* Here in IOUtils the Third Parameter true tells that the small chunks of data that comes need to be added to the same File */
            IOUtils.copy(fileItem.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(new File(threeDPath+"/"+year+"/"+series+"/"+uploadZipFileName),true));               
                }
            }
            return null;
        }   
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return handleError(new RuntimeException("Unexpected error while uploading ZIP", e));
        }
        return null;
    }
```